# Django mongoengine save data

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

In my Django project i have used Mysql and MongoDB as two database. And defined settings file like this.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_name'
},
'mongo_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME': '****',

},
```

}

I have defined all my models like this

```
class EntityType(Document):
  entity_type = fields.StringField()
```

Now when i want to store data in EntityType using Django shell its throwing error
`ConnectionError: You have not defined a default connection`

Please suggest what i am doing wrong

**Edit**

Have i added wrong engine in mongo_db database connection.I think i got confused between mongoengine and django-mongodb-engine

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you do:

```
entity_type = EntityType(....)
entity_type.save(using='mongo_db')
```

This should work

Comment: Do I need to change database engine. I think igot confused between mongoengine and django-mongodb-engine

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your database using mongoengine

```
from mongoengine import connect
connect(alias='alias_name', db='db_name', host='localhost', 
username='your_username', password='password_of_your_username', 
authentication_source='admin')
```